# Determine whether image is vector or raster with PHP

Tags: php, vector, imagick, raster

I am using Imagick with PHP to combine images uploaded by the user. For some images, I would like to check whether or not the original file uploaded is in vector format. Is there a way to do this with PHP?

I realise that Imagick converts vector images to raster, making this not as simple as I originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You Need To Know Which file extension is vactor. like `illustrator , corel or freehand file is vactor base.`
now you can check uploaded file with mime types.

like this.

```
$ext = ['ai','fhX','corelExtension'];

$file_name_parts = pathinfo($_FILE['file']['file_name']);

if( !in_array($file_name_parts['extension'], $ext) ) {
    $error = "sorry this file is not permitted. or not vactor file.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I am wondering however if there's a way of knowing whether the image is a vector without having to list mime types? Ideally using Imagick.

Comment: i think not possible. any ways if this answer is useful for you. please vote... i need votes to remove adds.